# Cannot read property 'toString" of undefined -- React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scss-mixins

[Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-solomon-2ffvw?file=/src/App.js).

I was about to start working on this app again. It worked perfectly about a month ago, however now I get the error: Cannot read property 'toString" of undefined

It doesn't pinpoint where the error is either.

Comment: In the sandbox there is a "problems" tab, click on the problem and it opens your breakpoints.scss file and highlights the first line, the comment. I tried removing them but the error keeps moving down and starts highlighting the CSS. I'm not familiar with scss.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the `create-react-app` environment.

Build your project off of the `parcel` environment, installing the needed react dependencies, and it will work.

They talk about this issue [here](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/75)